# redirect to action method from base controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4

I have initialized method in my base controller class which is called whenever any action method is executed. On every action method, I want to check my session and if it is null it should redirect to the login page.

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected IDataRepository _appData = new DataRepository();

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);

        if (SessionFactory.CurrentAdminUser == null)
        {
            RedirectToLogin();
        }
    }
 }
public ActionResult RedirectToLogin()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("AdminLogin", "Admin");
    }
```

it's calling this method but not redirecting to admin login method and keeps execution on and call method which is in flow so error will come.

In short i want to check whenever my application session gets null its should rediect to login page and its not convenient to check on all methods.please suggest me some good way.

Answer (score 23):

You're calling `RedirectToLogin()` which in turn simply returns a `RedirectToActionResult` that is not being used and does not affect the flow of the action.

Try this instead:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting();

    if (SessionFactory.CurrentAdminUser == null)
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(Url.Action("AdminLogin", "Admin"));
}
```

Alternatively, if you insist on overriding `Initialize`:

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);

    if (SessionFactory.CurrentAdminUser == null)
    {
        requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(Url.Action("AdminLogin", "Admin"));
        requestContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Also, check the `[Authorize]` filter, it may better suit your needs. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I couldn't use Url.Action. Can you advice which assembly I need to refer for that Url.Action ?

Comment: @Silvia, I assume it's `System.Web.Mvc`

Answer (score 2):

A simpler approach:

```
public void RedirectToLogin()
{
    RedirectToAction("AdminLogin", "Admin").ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
}
```